# serverless-domain-manager cannot be found by serverless deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, deployment, serverless

I was getting the below error while deploying the lambda on AWS using bitbucket pipeline

> Error: Could not set up basepath mapping. Try running sls create_domain first.
>
> Error: 'staging-api.simple.touchsuite.com' could not be found in API Gateway.
>
> ConfigError: Missing region in config
>
> at getDomain.then.then.catch (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/index.js:181:15)
>   at 
>   at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
>
> For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
>
> Get Support
>   Docs:   docs.serverless.com
>   Bugs:   github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
>   Issues: forum.serverless.com
>
> Your Environment Information
>   Operating System:          linux
>   Node Version:              8.10.0
>   Framework Version:         1.61.3
>   Plugin Version:            3.2.7
>   SDK Version:               2.3.0
>   Components Core Version:   1.1.2
>   Components CLI Version:    1.4.0

So, I updated the serverless-domain-manager to the newest version 3.3.1

I tried to deploy the lambda after updating the serverless-domain-manager and now I am getting the below error.

> Serverless Error
>
> Serverless plugin "serverless-domain-manager" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file.

serverless.yml snippet

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-log-forwarding
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  warmup:
    schedule: 'cron(0/10 12-23 ? * MON-FRI *)'
    prewarm: true
  headers:
    - Content-Type
    - X-Amz-Date
    - Authorization
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - TS-Staging
    - x-tss-correlation-id
    - x-tss-application-id

  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  domains:
    prod: api.simple.touchsuite.com
    staging: staging-api.simple.touchsuite.com
    dev: dev-api.simple.touchsuite.com
  customDomain:
    basePath: 'svc'
    domainName: ${self:custom.domains.${self:custom.stage}}
    stage: ${self:custom.stage}
```

bitbucket-pipeline.yml snippet

```
image: node:8.10.0

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          name: Run tests
          script:
            - npm install --global copy
            - npm install
            - NODE_ENV=test npm test
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          name: Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging   # set to test, staging or production
          script:
            - npm install --global copy
            - npm run deploy:staging
            - npm run deploy:integrations:staging
            - node -e 'require("./scripts/bitbucket.js").triggerPipeline()'
```

Need some insight, what am I missing that creating the error

Answer (score 2):

I have found with Bitbucket I needed to add an `npm install` command to make sure that my modules and the plugins were all installed before trying to run them. This may be what is missing in your case. You can also turn caching on for the resulting `node_modules` folder so that it doesn't have to download all modules every time you deploy.

Comment: I have added the bitbucket-pipeline.yml snippet. It was working correctly before, after I upgraded the serverless-domain-manager, I am getting the serverless-domain-manager not found

Comment: Do you want to make sure that the plugin is listed in your package.json?

Comment: I found out that the script was not able to install the plugin only using npm install --global copy and I added npm install after that in script part of pipeline and worked correctly. Thanks for the help